# How to extract year and week number using base R?

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, data-analysis

I have the following data frame:

```
id   created_at                   year_weak
 1     2016-01-01T12:11:03.383Z    2016-01
 2     2016-01-04T12:11:03.383Z    2016-01
 3     2016-01-06T12:11:03.383Z    2016-01
 4     2016-01-11T12:11:03.383Z    2016-02
 5     2016-01-12T12:11:03.383Z    2016-02
```

currently i have following code using lubridate package:

```
paste(year(as.Date(df$created_at)),week(as.Date(df$created_at)),sep = "-")
```

i want to do the same thing using base R , how can i do it in Base R?

Comment: is the data type of "created_at" a string or already a `Date` or `POSIXct`?

Comment: Actually, it is a factor i have not changed the type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This following works with base **R** commands:

```
year <- format(as.Date(df$created_at)+2, "%Y")
week <- format(as.Date(df$created_at)+2, "%U")

paste(year,week,sep = "-")
```

Note: You have to add 2 days, because the 1st January 2016 was a Friday and this would give you a week of 0. In `format()` the week starts with Sunday.

Regards,
J_F

Comment: thanks what if i want to apply it to different years with different starting day?

Comment: read the manual: "%U

    Week of the year as decimal number (00–53) using Sunday as the first day 1 of the week (and typically with the first Sunday of the year as day 1 of week 1). The US convention."